# How does python handle KeyboardInterrupt during infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, while-loop, keyboardinterrupt

When I run this code:

```
while 1:
    try:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

and I press `ctrl+c` to try to terminate the program through a KeyboardInterrupt, I am usually, but not always successful. Most of the time, my first attempt at `ctrl+c` terminates the program, but sometimes, I need to press `ctrl+c` twice.

Compare that with this code:

```
from time import sleep

while 1:
    try:
        sleep(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

With this code, no matter how many times I press `ctrl+c`, the program never terminates.

My assumption is that in the first scenario, my KeyboardInterrupt usually works because the `pass` statements executes so quickly that I am more likely to press `ctrl+c` during the while loop condition check (which is not in the try block) than during the pass statement execution (which is in the try block).

And, in the second example, I assume the sleep function must take much longer to execute than the while loop condition check such that I am almost guaranteed to press `ctrl+c` during its execution (thus catching the KeyboardInterrupt in the try block and continuing the loop).

Can anyone confirm my assumption or give an alternate reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are `pass`ing the keyboard interrupt in both cases, the program just continues with the `while` loop.

With the second case, due to the `sleep` in the body of the `try` block, there is a mu8ch higher chance of your `KeyboardInterrupt` hitting the process during that `sleep` - which means your `except` block is almost guaranteed to be executed. Which means that your program just carries on. You can test this by adding a print in the `except` block.

```
from time import sleep

while 1:
    try:
        sleep(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('exc')
        pass
```

If I run this and press `Ctrl+C` I get:

```
>python so_test.py
exc
exc
exc
exc
exc
exc
exc
exc
```

With each `Ctrl+C` the `except` block is executed, but your program continues on.

In the first first case however, due to the lack of any delay (i.e. `sleep`) in the `try` block, the programs is just as likely to be executing outside the `try` block (before entering it, or after) when the `KeyboardInterrupt` hits your process. Which means that your exception is not handled, and that ends the program. If however, the interrupt hits the process inside the `try`-block, the program will continue. Check this:

```
while 1:
    try:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('exc')
        pass
```

And you can get this:

```
>python so_test.py
exc
exc
exc
exc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    pass
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Hope that clears up the confusion.